# DB2 String parse

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am new to DB2 completely but I have some knowledge of MySQL.  Here is what I am trying to do:

I am accepting an input comma delimited string (stringPassedIn), for examples sake let's say

```
stringPassedIn = 'bob,mary,joe,joffrey,ed';
```

and parse the string by comma then run an insert statement on each value parsed.  I have the INSERT query down but I am not sure how to write the string parser using DB2.  Here is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE aCount INT;
DECLARE mySubString VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE tmp INT;

SET aCount = 0;
WHILE aCount < length(stringPassedIn) DO
    SET mySubString = SUBSTR(stringPassedIn, 1, LOCATE(',', stringPassedIn));
    tmp = LOCATE(',',stringPassedIn); 
    // INSERT STATEMENT HERE (THIS INSERT WORKS)
    SET aCount = tmp;
END WHILE;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  All the examples I am seeing is if I am getting data from the tables and not parsing before putting data in at all.

Comment: That looks mostly okay.  What errors are you getting (or other problems)?  You may have to define a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XML parser built into SQL servers by prefixing with `<name>`, postfixing with `</name>` and replacing `,` with `</name><name>`.

Now it looks like an XML representation of a table with one column.

Comment: None of the data is XML.  It's just a simple string.

Comment: @seroth -- exactly.  SQL servers are better at parsing XML that is why I show you how to convert it into XML.  It is **easier** to parse if you do so.